# Is deleting sshd.log file safe?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

Recently I started running out of space in my computer and I notice there is a file in the path `C:\openssh\OpenSSH-Win64\sshd.log` that is almost 19GB in size.

Is it safe to delete this file? and does anyone know how can I prevent the file to reach that size again? I've been looking that up in different forums but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer.

Comment: [Github Issue 138](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1) makes mention of unusually large logs and the solution. Have you looked in the logs to see what they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a log file, which usually contains useful informations, such as who accessed the SSH server, when, from where and so on.

But the Windows developers probably broke something so it is gradually filling with junk (snippet from your log file would be good in the question, but normal traffic can not reasonably generate so many information) such as:

```
 5920 11:02:05 068 fatal: WaitForMultipleObjects failed with error code [87]
```

This was discussed in the [Github Issue 138](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/138) and it should be fixed with latest version. So unless you need the logs for some auditing, you are safe to truncate that file and after the update, it should not rise to this size again.